# Symfony 3.4.20 and FOSUserBundle - 'remember me' not working

Tags: php, symfony, remember-me

With the following relevant configuration in `security.yml`:

```
security:
    firewalls:
        # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        main:
            pattern:
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager

            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true
            logout_on_user_change: true
            remember_me:
                secret: '%secret%'
                secure: true
                httponly: true
                lifetime: 31536000
```

The remember me session token is only lasting for the browser session rather than the year as specified in the configuration.  Could this be due to the `secure: true` setting?  My development machine doesn't have any TLS installed, so could that be the culprit?  Or is there something else I should be looking for?  From looking at [the documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/security/remember_me.html), it looks like I'm setting things up correctly, so I'm at a bit of a loss.

Comment: I had the same issue, my problem was my user entitty serializer that was missing the salt so it would login properly but as soon as you would come back it wouldn't deserialize my token

Comment: This being said, I would recommend to not use FOSUB

Comment: I'm at a point in this project where I *can't* switch from FOSUB to something else.  Can you write your solution as an answer?  Maybe I can cludge something together from it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my gut feeling about `secure: true` was correct. I set it to `false` during a test, and the cookie was correct.  Since my development machine doesn't have SSL/TLS, it can't send a secure cookie if that's what's configured.  It should work on my production server, given I do have working SSL/TLS in that environment.

Answer (score 0):

Though it is late, this might help somebody.
Adding `require_previous_session: false` option under `form_login:` fixed my problem.

 Just like this

`form_login:`

    `require_previous_session: false`

According to https://symfony.com/doc/3.1/reference/configuration/security.html,

by default, a session must exist before submitting an authentication request. So, if you want to implement remember me function, you need to set `require_previous_session` to false